# Unable to ssh to my VPS

Tags: 14.04, ssh

I purchased a VPS from namecheap and now I am trying to ssh in to it (Ultimate goal is to set up Ghost Blogging Platform on it).

I tried the following command -

```
$ ssh root@_ip_address_to_my_vps_
```

I get the following error -

```
The authenticity of host '_ip_address_to_my_vps_ (_ip_address_to_my_vps_)'
can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is _fingerprint_redacted_.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? y
Host key verification failed.
```

Yes, I know that there are tons of "host key verification failed" threads out there. But none of the solutions work. They all ask to generate the ssk key which I did as follows -

```
$ ssh-keygen -R _ip_address_to_my_vps_
```

The output indicates that the know_hosts file was updated but I continue to get the same error.

Any idea what I still haven't done?

Answer (score 0):

On debian (and as far as I remember on 14.04 too) we have to type the full word "yes" instead of just "y" to answer the question "Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?".

Otherwise there is a prompt telling "Please type 'yes' or 'no':"

Typing a full "yes" may be your solution (although the lack of error message is strange).

Comment: No. Does not work.

Comment: By the way, "ssh-keygen -R " does not generate a new key, it does delete any previously recorded public keys for this server (at least for this IP), cf man ssh-keygen.

Comment: You should not use this command everytime in your case, your problem is the exact opposite (you do not have a recorded public key, hence the error "The authenticity ... can't be established."

Comment: Anyway, the behaviour of your ssh client is strange. What is the version installed on your computer ? (apt-cache policy openssh-client)

Answer (score 0):

I normally use something like

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

without the ip address of the vps like you did and it works for me. From the ssh-keygen manpage:

> -R hostname
>   Removes all keys belonging to hostname from a known_hosts file. This option is useful to delete hashed hosts (see the -H option above).

Which I don't think is what you want